# how to repeat buttons (start / stop) loop based on array list using angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular8

```
<li *ngFor="let list of lists  "  class="fetch" id="name" >

    Name:{{list.name}}  <!-- This Name has the array values ex: j1, j2, j3 -->
   
    <button  style="font-size: 11px;border-radius: 8px;font-weight: bold;background-color: green;" 
    *ngIf="isCollapsed" id="name" (click)=" toggleCollapse()"> START</button> 
    <button style="font-size: 11px;border-radius: 8px;font-weight: bold;background-color: red;" 
     *ngIf="!isCollapsed" id="name" (click)=" toggleCollapse()">STOP</button>
</li>
```

For Example: I have array list given above based on those how can i repeat this start / stop buttons for each item.

if I run this code it will show start / stop button for all items but my requirement is when click start / Stop for particular item (ex: j1) than only j1 will start remains should be same idle.

can anyone please help me on the same.

Comment: can you share some of the typescript code that backs `toggleCollapse()`?

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like the `id` for all buttons is `name` shouldn't that be `{{list.name}}` as well?
It depends on your `toggleCollapse` function.
Please fill in a minimal working code example for a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to add another ngFor loop inside your existing one?

```
<li *ngFor="let list of lists  "  class="fetch" id="name" >
    Name:{{list.name}}  <!-- This Name has the array values ex: j1, j2, j3 -->
    <span *ngFor="let key of list?.name">
      <button *ngIf="isCollapsed" (click)="toggleCollapse()">{{key}} START</button> 
      <button *ngIf="!isCollapsed" (click)=" toggleCollapse()">{{key}} STOP</button>
    </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly understand the question, but instead of using a central flag `isCollapsed`, try to include this flag in each item of the `lists` array. Then the items could be set individually.

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  lists = [
    { name: 'j1', isCollapsed: true },
    { name: 'j2', isCollapsed: true },
    { name: 'j3', isCollapsed: true },
    { name: 'j4', isCollapsed: true }
  ];

  start(name) {
    console.log(`started ${name}!`);
  }

  stop(name) {
    console.log(`stopped ${name}!`);
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<li *ngFor="let list of lists" class="fetch" id="name">
  Name: {{list.name}}
  
  <button 
    style="font-size: 11px;border-radius: 8px;font-weight: bold;background-color: green;" 
    id="name" 
    (click)="list.isCollapsed = !list.isCollapsed; list.isCollapsed ? stop(list.name) : start(list.name)"
  >
    {{ list.isCollapsed ? 'START' : 'STOP' }}
  </button>
</li>

<pre>{{lists | json}}</pre>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mtvbpj)

Comment: Thanks for you replay @Michael D, Here my requirement is the values j1, j2 ,... these are not static to fix standard code. the id's will change dynamically and according to values (j series) the buttons will added.

Comment: @BhargaviV: That's why I called it an _example_. You could interpret and adjust the example to your specific needs. The primary question of binding individual buttons to elements of an array is answered. If you facing in binding a dynamic array, you need to create a new question and provide what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks @Michael the actual requirement you can find in the below link   --- 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62839939/how-to-call-the-api-by-passing-id-dynamically-from-server-using-angular?noredirect=1#comment111126593_62839939